# add clock and day to terminal window

Tags: command-line

When I run the command `watch df`, I see a clock and time on the right upper corner of the terminal window. Is there any command that I can use to visualize time/date in terminal window? it seems that this is possible, because command `watch df` can do it?

Comment: sure - a simple script can do this.  But terminals by themselves do not do this.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do something similar to `watch df` in regard of adding a clock on the right upper corner of terminal window:

```
while true; do echo -ne "\e[s\e[0;$((COLUMNS-27))H$(date)\e[u"; sleep 1; done &
```

Adjust the sleep value as you want to update time accordingly